# Using FFTW on tensor

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, mpi, fftw

Dear All I tried to find an answer googling but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm using fftw in an MPI Fotran application and i need to compute forward and backward transform of a 3D array of tensor component by component, and while in fourier space compute some complex tensorial quantities.
In order to make the array used by ffftw useful and don't spend a lot of time moving data from an array to another one the option that came into my mind was to declare a 5d dimensional array: i.e

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

call MPI_INIT( mpi_err )
call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_rank, mpi_err )
call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_size, mpi_err )

integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: FFTDIM=3  !fft dimension
integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: fft_L                !x direction
integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: fft_M                !y direction
integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: fft_N                !z direction
complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), pointer :: fft_in(:,:,:,:,:), fft_out(:,:,:,:,:)
type(C_PTR) :: fft_plan_fwd, fft_plan_bkw, fft_datapointer
integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: fft_alloc_local, fft_local_n0, fft_local_0_start

include 'mpif.h'
include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'

call fftw_mpi_init

fft_L=problem_dim(1)
fft_M=problem_dim(2)
fft_N=problem_dim(3)


! CALCULATE LOCAL SIZE OF FFT VARIABLE FOR EACH COMPOENNT

fft_alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_3d(fft_N,fft_M,fft_L, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
            fft_local_n0, fft_local_0_start)

! allocate data pointer
fft_datapointer = fftw_alloc_complex(9*int(fft_alloc_local,C_SIZE_T))

! link pointers to the same array
call c_f_pointer(fft_datapointer, fft_in,  [ FFTDIM, FFTDIM, fft_L, fft_M, fft_local_n0])
call c_f_pointer(fft_datapointer, fft_out, [ FFTDIM, FFTDIM, fft_L, fft_M, fft_local_n0])


! create plans
fft_plan_fwd = fftw_MPI_plan_dft_3d(fft_N, fft_M, fft_L, & !dimension
               fft_in(1,1,:,:,:), fft_out(1,1,:,:,:), & !inpu, output
               MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE)

fft_plan_bkw = fftw_MPI_plan_dft_3d(fft_N, fft_M, fft_L, & !dimension
            fft_in(1,1,:,:,:), fft_out(1,1,:,:,:), & !inpu, output
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE)
```

Now, if I use this piece of code and the number of processors is a multiple of 2 (2,4,8...), everything works fine, but if I use 6, the application will give an error. how could I solve this issue?
do you have any better strategies instead of allocating a 5d array and without moving to many data??

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new and maybe i did something wrong (I just justified it of 4 space) and the code didn't come out "pretty".

Comment: @AndreaRovinelli Never mind, I don't get the first comment at all. BTW if you are using Fortran 2003 I recommend `use mpi` instead of `include 'mpif.h'`.

Comment: Stackoverflow uses [Google prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for code syntax highlighting. It doesn't support Fortran. That is all.

Comment: @AndreaRovinelli You should specify WHICH error you get and how your code looks like in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this  problem utilizing the **fffw_mpi_plan_many** interface
the code performing this computation follows here. It calculate a 3D(LxMxN) complex to complex transform of tensor component by component (11,12,...) utilizing **MPI** capabilities. The extent on the third dimension(N) must be divisible for the number of core utilized

```
program test_fftw

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    include 'mpif.h'
    include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: L = 8 ! extent of x data
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: M = 8 ! extent of y data
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: N = 192 ! extent of z data
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: FFT_12_DIM = 3 ! tensor dimension
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: ll, mm, nn, i, j
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) :: fout

    ! many plan data variables
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: howmany=9 ! numer of eleemnt of the tensor
    integer :: rank=3                ! rank of the transform
    integer(C_INTPTR_T), dimension(3) :: fft_dims ! array containing data extent
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: alloc_local_many, fft_local_n0, fft_local_0_start
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), pointer :: fft_data(:,:,:,:,:)
    type(C_PTR) ::fft_datapointer, plan_many


    integer :: ierr, myid, nproc





    ! Initialize
    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
    call fftw_mpi_init()


    ! write data dimenion in reversed order
    fft_dims(3) = L
    fft_dims(2) = M
    fft_dims(1) = N

    ! use of alloc many
    alloc_local_many = fftw_mpi_local_size_many(rank, & ! rank of the transform in this case 3
        fft_dims, & ! array containing data dimension in reversed order
        howmany, &  ! numebr of transform to compute in this case 3x3=9
        FFTW_MPI_DEFAULT_BLOCK, & !default block size
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, & ! mpi communicator
        fft_local_n0, & ! local numebr of slice by core
        fft_local_0_start) ! local shift on the last dimension


    fft_datapointer = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local_many) ! allocate aligned memory for the data

    ! associate data pointer with allocated memory: note  natural order
    call c_f_pointer(fft_datapointer, fft_data, [FFT_12_DIM,FFT_12_DIM,L,M, fft_local_n0])


    ! create the plan for many inplace multidimensional transform
    plan_many = fftw_mpi_plan_many_dft( &
        rank , fft_dims, howmany, &
        FFTW_MPI_DEFAULT_BLOCK, FFTW_MPI_DEFAULT_BLOCK, &
        fft_data, fft_data, &
        MPI_COMM_WORLD,  FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )


    ! initialize data to some function my_function(i,j)
    do nn = 1, fft_local_n0
        do mm = 1, M
            do ll = 1, L
                do i = 1, FFT_12_DIM
                    do j = 1, FFT_12_DIM

                        fout = ll*mm*nn*i*j
                        fft_data(i,j,ll,mm,nn) = fout

                    end do
                end do
            end do
        end do
    enddo

    call fftw_mpi_execute_dft(plan_many, fft_data, fft_data)!

    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_many)
    call fftw_mpi_cleanup()
    call fftw_free(fft_datapointer)
    call mpi_finalize(ierr)




end program test_fftw
```

thanks everyone for the help !!